# Different cases for dict when using type() and isinstance()

Tags: python

I have a section of code that contains the following line:

```
if isinstance(data, dict) and type(data) != dict:
    ...
```

In what cases would this apply? If a simple dictionary was passed here, wouldn't `if isinstance(data, dict)` alone be enough?

Comment: I think that it would be true if the `data` would be an instance of a subclass of the class `dict`

Comment: @hhhh Go through this doc: https://premaseem.wordpress.com/2017/10/11/python-difference-between-type-and-isinstance/

This should help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Comment: *"wouldn't `if isinstance(data, dict)` alone be enough?"* - enough for what? Isn't this your code? What is it supposed to check?

Answer (score 3):

You code tests whether your object is an instance of a `dict`, but its concrete type is not `dict`. In other words, it checks whether your object is an instance of a *proper* subclass of dict.

Here is a quick example to demonstrate the difference:

```
class custom_dict(dict):
    pass

d = custom_dict({1: 2})

isinstance(d, dict), type(d) == dict
# (True, False)
```

```
>>> type(d)
__main__.custom_dict
```

Comment: It is difficult to find the right language here :) But within the domain of OOP, an instance of a dict subclass *is* a dict. Its conrete type is not though.

Comment: @user2390182 I agree, I'm not a OOP specialist though, feel free to edit if you have an idea to improve the language ;)